# Is Agent Coulson an LMD?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

If Agent Phil Coulson did die in **The Avengers** movie, and a big ole hole where your heart used to be would pretty much indicate death, could he be a LMD?

LMD = *Life Model Decoy* : A **S.H.I.E.L.D.** designed robot/android that duplicates all aspects of the living person they are posing as.

*I bring this question up for two reasons* :

**1-** Back in a 1977 issue of **Defenders** and then recently in **Secret Avengers** one of the LMD's of Nick Fury went rogue and called himself **Max Fury**.  He had aligned himself with Scorpio, join the Shadow Council and was even a member of the Descendants.

**2-** In **The Avengers** movie Tony Stark tries to avoid a phone call from Agent Coulson by claiming, in an answering machine voice, that the caller has reached '*Tony Stark's Life Model Decoy*' instead of Tony himself.

I find it interesting that it was brought up in the only other thing Joss Whedon has done for MARVEL...

Comment: Polls and questions soliciting opinions or vague input are not allowed on StackExchange (as, even though they're in a question format, they have no right answer and aren't suited to a Q&A format). So, in the future, just pose the core question rather than asking if anyone else agrees with your theory or inviting free-form discussions. Such discussions should be reserved for the chat rooms.

Comment: Okay. Thank you Lèse majesté

Comment: Also, this is clearly a "wait and see" question. We will get the answer in a future  Agents of SHIELD episode, because since the begining some scenes are dedicated to make this very question an important part of the overall plot.

Comment: Just a bit to stir the pot, he did have an actual dream in the most recent episode, I don't think LMD's are capable of dreaming.

Comment: [Might be](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/14759/was-coulson-dead-or-near-dead-is-tahiti-a-metaphor/14766#14766) but its only speculation at the moment.

Comment: @Monty129 was he dreaming of electric sheep?

Comment: Read last line from [Oliver's answer](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/14759/was-coulson-dead-or-near-dead-is-tahiti-a-metaphor) for more insight. That interview suggest that most speculation are wrong and they might come with something entirely new.

Comment: @Monty129, Clearly, Coulson is actually a Doll/Active and SHIELD is really the Rossum Corporationg.

Comment: @phantom42 He even said the line "Did I fall asleep?" in the exact same way all the Dolls did on Dollhouse too!  That was the first thing I thought of.

Comment: I am going to vote to reopen this. The events of the *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* series (especially surrounding Coulson’s resurrection) make it pretty clear that he’s not an LMD. Or, depending on your perspective, absolutely certain that he is one. ;)

Comment: While this question would be easy to answer, it really seems like it already has been.  We have other questions that do explain how Coulson is alive.  What does this one add?

Comment: We could reopen it then close it as a duplicate. That would give the most useful outcome.